# Delete element from list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with 1000 elements, and I want to delete all elements from index 400 (including) until the last element.

Comment: Do you want or need  anything more than `list = list[[1;;399]]` ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Thank you. I added your comment as an answer.

Comment: `Drop[val, {400, -1}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by "High Performance Mark". This is the way to go:

```
val=Table[i,{i,1,1000}];
val=val[[1;;399]];
```